# in icecream scheduler log, what does "<host> not eligible " mean?

Tags: ice

While diagnosing slow build times using [icecream](https://github.com/icecc/icecream). I encounted several instances of the following message in the icecc-scheduler logs:

```
<hostname> not eligible
```

What is this trying to communicate to me?

Answer (score 1):

This could stem from a few scenarios and they are documented in the [source code here](https://github.com/icecc/icecream/blob/master/scheduler/compileserver.cpp#L156)

```
bool CompileServer::is_eligible(const Job *job)
{
    bool jobs_okay = int(m_jobList.size()) < m_maxJobs;
    bool load_okay = m_load < 1000;
    bool version_okay = job->minimalHostVersion() <= protocol;
    return jobs_okay
           && (m_chrootPossible || job->submitter() == this)
           && load_okay
           && version_okay
           && m_acceptingInConnection
           && can_install(job).size()
           && this->check_remote(job);
}
```

I'd check to make sure that each host is:

1. iceccd is run as root
2. each host has the same version of icecc installed. Verify with `/usr/bin/icecc --version`
3. plenty of free space left
4. maximum number of jobs has not been exceeded